# How to set default colormap in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

Especially when working with grayscale images it is tedious to set the color map for every `imshow` command as `imshow(i, cmap='gray')`. How can I set the default color map matplotlib uses to grayscale or any other colormap?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To change the default colormap only for the current interactive session or one script use

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('image', cmap='gray')
```

For versions of `matplotlib` prior to 2.0 you have to use the rcParams dict. This still works in newer versions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'
```

To change the default colormap permanently edit the matplotlibrc configuration file and add the line `image.cmap: gray`. 
Replace the value gray with any other valid colormap according to your needs. 
The config file should be at  `~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`, but you can find out the exact location with

```
mpl.matplotlib_fname()
```

This is especially useful if you have multiple matplotlib versions in different virtual environments.

See also http://txt.arboreus.com/2014/10/21/how-to-set-default-colormap-in-matplotlib.html
and for general configuration of Matplotlib http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Answer (score 23):

You can do either,

```
plt.set_cmap('jet')
```

or

```
plt.rcParams['image.cmap']='jet'
```

However note that if you are passing value for `color` parameter in any of the APIs then this default will be ignored. In that case you should do something like this:

```
color = plt.cm.hsv(r) # r is 0 to 1 inclusive
line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D(xdata, ydata, color=color)
```

Comment: [Why People Hate Jet – and You Should Too](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/)