# Pandas DataFrame Plot: Permanently change default colormap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

For extensive plotting scripts, I use matplotlibs rcParams to configure some standard plot settings for pandas DataFrames.

This works well for colors and font sizes but not for the default colormap as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185037/how-to-set-default-colormap-in-matplotlib)

Here's my current approach:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm


# global plotting options
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2.5
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'silver'
plt.rcParams['xtick.color'] = 'k'
plt.rcParams['ytick.color'] = 'k'
plt.rcParams['text.color'] = 'k'
plt.rcParams['axes.labelcolor'] = 'k'
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'Blues'  # this doesn't show any effect


# dataframe with random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3))

# this shows the standard colormap
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()

# this shows the right colormap
df.plot(kind='bar', cmap=cm.get_cmap('Blues'))
plt.show()
```

The first plot does not use the colormap via colormap (which it should normally do?):
[image]

It only works if I pass it as an argument as in the second plot:

[image]

Is there any way to define the standard colormap for pandas DataFrame plots, permanently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported, official way to do it; you are stuck because of pandas's internal [_get_standard_colors function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py) that hardcodes the use of `matplotlib.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']` and falls back to `list('bgrcmyk')`:

```
colors = list(plt.rcParams.get('axes.color_cycle',
                               list('bgrcmyk')))
```

There are various hacks you can use, however; one of the simplest, which works for all `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` calls, is to wrap `pandas.tools.plotting.plot_frame`:

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import pandas.tools.plotting as pdplot

def plot_with_matplotlib_cmap(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault("colormap", matplotlib.rcParams.get("image.cmap", "Blues"))
    return pdplot.plot_frame_orig(*args, **kwargs)

pdplot.plot_frame_orig = pdplot.plot_frame
pdplot.plot_frame = plot_with_matplotlib_cmap
pd.DataFrame.plot = pdplot.plot_frame
```

To test in a notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000,10))).plot()
```

...yields:

[image: blue_plot]