# How can I set a default value for cmap in a pcolormash as a xarray plot?

Tags: python, plot, default, python-xarray

In my Jupyter Notebook I am plotting various xarrays as pcolormeshs via the `some_xa.plot()` function. Now I want to plot them as a certain cmap, e.g. `cmap = 'RdBu_r'` instead of the default 'viridis', without passing this to every single call for a plot.

In other words: How can I set `cmap = 'RdBu_r'` as default for plotting xarrays in this Notebook?

I've tried to use the default of matplotlib:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0, 10.0) 
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = ('RdBu_r')
```

While the figure size is changed for all plots, the cmap isn't influenced at all and presents 'viridis' every time, except I enter a value that is not recognized, resulting in a ValueError.

Comment: Have you seen this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185037/how-to-set-default-colormap-in-matplotlib

Comment: @Sandertjuhh: just checked, but neither option did the job. Seems that `xarray.plot()` somehow overwrites the matplotlib defaults (?)