# Image has 3 channels but it's in a grayscale color. If I change it to 1 channel, it goes into RGB

Tags: python, matplotlib

I started doing some image-processing in python and I've stumbled upon an issue which is kind of confusing from a beginner's perspective. I have a dataset of 1131 np arrays (images) of MRI on knee. The shape of the images is kind of weird, it is `(44, 256, 256)` meaning that one array has 44 images with size of 256x256 pixels. For instance, if I show the 22nd image (middle one), with `plt.imshow(image[22])` this is what I get:

[image]

This image clearly seems like an RGB but if I do `image[22].shape`, I get `(256,256)` which is expected but at the same time confusing because it says that it has no channels and from what I know, images that don't have channels should be in grayscale color but clearly this is not the case here.

I dived deeper and tried executing `cv2.cvtColor(image[22, :, :], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` which resulted in:

[image]

This does seem like a grayscale image but the shape of this image is `(256, 256, 3)`. This is so confusing for me and can someone point it out why does this happen, grayscale image with 3 channels and colorful image with no channels and how can I have this `image[22]` in grayscale mode with 1 channel? I need it in 1 channel because I want to do a feature extraction but if I do it this way, pure `image[22]` and the "grayscale" variant have the same values for each feature but from the looks of it, they do not seem exactly.

The numpy array (image) can be taken from [here](https://pastebin.com/aWyPXrBS).

Comment: That's the default colormap of matplotlib you see in the first image (called Viridis). It doesn't mean the image is not grayscale, just that it displays it in a specific colormap. Check here how to default matplotlib to grayscale. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185037/how-to-set-default-colormap-in-matplotlib

Comment: your image is a 3D image, not a 2D image with colors. Each of those 44 is a different "depth". Its likely just few slices of the knee.

Comment: if anyone wants to flag this as a duplicate of any of the previously asked questions along those lines...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image **is** monochrome, but by default `imshow` is mapping pixels to the default colormap, `viridis`.

See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by @thebiss, if you change the order of the dimensions with transpose(), you can view any three images from your stack of 44 as RGB by using imshow(). In the example below I am viewing slices 10,11 and 12.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random([44,256,256])
datar = np.transpose(data ,axes=(1,2,0))
print(data.shape,datar.shape)

plt.imshow(datar[:,:,10:13])
```