# My images with 1 channel are full color, but when I add the third dimension (3 channel) it is in grayscale

Tags: python, image-processing, rgb, grayscale, imshow

I am trying to get the shape of images in my custom data generator :

```
for j in range(len(image)):
    img = np.array(image[j])
    print(img.shape)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

The `img.shape` shows `(128, 87)` without the third dimension, so I expect to see a grayscale image, while the `plt.imshow(img)` shows the full-color image.

On the other hand, I converted grayscale to RGB using the following code:

```
def grayscale_to_rgb(input_image):
   input_image = np.expand_dims(input_image, -1)
   input_image_3_channel =input_image.repeat(3, axis=-1)
   return input_image_3_channel
```

the image shape will be (128,87,3) but I see a grayscale image using plt.imshow(img).

I have already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75449454/image-has-3-channels-but-its-in-a-grayscale-color-if-i-change-it-to-1-channel). What I understood is the grayscale image is still grayscale, but `imshow` shows the default `cmap`. So, how can I see the RGB image in color?

Comment: The default [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/dflt_style_changes.html#colormap) of matplotlib is `viridis`. When displaying an image with a single channel matplotlib applies colormap, and when displaying RGB there is no colormap. You may try [other packages](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/display-images-using-python) for displaying the image. Or select gray colormap as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3823822/4926757).

Comment: Your `grayscale_to_rgb()` function is producing an image in which the red, green, and blue components of each pixel are equal - the only pixel colors possible are shades of gray.  If you want there to be any color in the result, you'd have to handle the three components unequally.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for your reply. Can you provide the code for that ?

Comment: Code for *what*, exactly?  How do you want colors to be assigned to your image?

Comment: @jasonharper  how can i handle the three components unequally if i want to see the rgb images in color ?

Comment: You can do whatever you want - there's no inherent color in the original image, so there's no proper way to make up colors for it.  For example, set the green and blue components to 0, to make the image red - or perhaps multiply them by 0.5, for a more subtle reddish tint.