# Change the default colormap in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Matpltolib seems to apply the [`tab10` colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) by default.

[image]

How can I change the default colormap and use a different colormap instead, e.g. `Set3`?

I tried `plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'Set3'` and `plt.set_cmap('Set3')` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103503/5696601). However, non of the two options worked.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['image.cmap']='Set3'
plt.set_cmap('Set3')

species = ('Adelie', 'Chinstrap', 'Gentoo')
sex_counts = {
    'Male': np.array([73, 34, 61]),
    'Female': np.array([73, 34, 58]),
}

width = 0.6  # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bottom = np.zeros(3)

for sex, sex_count in sex_counts.items():
    p = ax.bar(species, sex_count, width, label=sex, bottom=bottom)
    bottom += sex_count

    ax.bar_label(p, label_type='center')

ax.set_title('Number of penguins by sex')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The default colors for the bars come from the cycler, not from the default colormap. E.g. `plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = plt.cycler(color=plt.cm.Set3.colors)`.  The default colormap for functions such as `plt.imshow(...)` is 'viridis' which is meant to color continuous data.

Comment: That's the answer! Thank you!